# Different UI for same html element in different web browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, browser

> I am amazed why different web browsers show different UI for same html element. I heard the term **UI Backend** but I am not sure from where browser gets this UI. If it takes it from OS then it should be consistent for all browsers on the same OS. But even on the same OS, browsers show different UI. Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Next are the **Firefox and Chrome** buttons
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The appearance is defined by the browser's "user agent stylesheet", which is basically the default CSS the browser uses when no other CSS is defined for an element.

Every browser defines its own user agent stylesheet.

Comment: Where this style-sheet is ? Inside browser or OS ?

Answer (score 0):

You can style buttons how you want using CSS.

There's really good information about it on [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css3_buttons.asp).

*Example CSS for a button:*

```
.styled-button {
    background-color: blue;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: I just want to know from where browsers getting this UI.